# How do I set the background color of an HTML Frame?

Tags: html, frames

I have a legacy website using frames. The pages within the frame do not use a white background and hence, I get an annoying "white flash" while the pages in the frames transition.  I think this can be fixed by changing the background color of the `<frame>`, but no matter what is entered, Internet Explorer will NOT see anything but white.  Firefox appears to accept the background color, but not so with IE.

NOTE: please don't flame me on using frames -- I know; heck, I think I've even preached it a time or too ... lol...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this, rather obscure, piece of information;

Notice the `**AllowTransparency**` attribute -- That did the trick -- now, the RightBackground class can set the color as expected.  Without the attribute, the color stays white (#ffffff), regardless.

Reference can be found here: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/tagpages/f/frame.htm

```
<frame  allowTransparency="true" class="RightBackground" src="BottomRight.asp" marginheight="0" marginwidth="10px" name="BottomRight" />
```

Just FYI, the contents of RightBackground just sets the background color:

```
 <style type="text/css">
  .RightBackground
  {
     background-color: #EAF4D9;
  }
 </style>
```

Comment: It seems in Chrome class does not work here, but direct `style="background-color: #EAF4D9;"` on `frame` does work.